# Generate a series between 2 column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following structure:

| FromAccount | ToAccount | Team | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 150 | a | 5 |
| 151 | 300 | b | 4 |
| 301 | 322 | c | 4 |

I would like to run an SQL query on the table that would return a +1 series for the FromAccount to ThruAccount with the Team and Location columns that belong to that series.
I think this table would look something like this where a record is returned for each +1 value in the From Thru Span.

| Account | Team | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | a | 5 |
| 101 | a | 5 |
| 102 | a | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 149 | a | 5 |
| 150 | a | 5 |
| 151 | b | 4 |
| 152 | b | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 300 | c | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 321 | c | 4 |
| 322 | c | 4 |

Can this be done in SQL Server?

Comment: a Typo! thank you for the help this did what I need it to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `101` was just missing due to a typo, we can use a recursive CTE to generate all the numbers between the lowest from and the highest to, then join to them.

```
DECLARE @min int, @max int;

SELECT @min = MIN(FromAccount), @max = MAX(ToAccount)
  FROM dbo.TableName;

WITH n(n) AS (SELECT @min UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < @max
)
SELECT Account = n.n,
  t.Team, t.Location
FROM dbo.TableName AS t
INNER JOIN n
ON n.n BETWEEN t.FromAccount AND t.ToAccount
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```